# Java program works when browser is Safari but not Opera/Firefox/Chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, safari, opera

I have a simple Java program that includes a robot which clicks things inside of a browser based on pixel location. It works on Safari, but not on Opera. Why is this? Is it because of the Java version I have? Is it because Opera is a 32-bit browser? Could somebody explain to me how to allow the Java program to run when my browser is Opera?

For reference:
http://help.opera.com/opera/Mac/1558/en/index.html
(See bottom where it discusses why Java may not be working.)

**EDIT:** I'm running a Mac OS X 64-bit machine.

**EDIT:** I even restored to Java SE 6.

**EDIT:** I even switched to Firefox, a 64-bit browser, but the java program still won't work. Any idea anybody?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different browsers have different pixel colors for the same thing.